# unknown column error in insert mysql query in php?

Tags: php, mysql, insert

Despite reading quite many posts i cannot solve this error- 
Unknown column 'alt.atheism1111' in 'field list'
the fields filename,category may have . in the middle of numbers or words,
im using phpmyadmin for database

```
function insert_rec($cat,$file,$wordid,$synsetid,$seqno)
{
    $cat=mysql_real_escape_string($cat);
    $file=mysql_real_escape_string($file);
    $wordid=mysql_real_escape_string($wordid);
    $synsetid=mysql_real_escape_string($synsetid);
    $seqno=mysql_real_escape_string($seqno);
    echo $cat."  ". $file ."  ". $wordid."  " . $synsetid."  " . $seqno;
     $sql="INSERT  INTO `wordnet50`.`table`  (`category`,`filename`,`wordid`,`synsetid`,`seqno`) VALUES (`" . $cat . "`,`" . $file. "`,`" . $wordid. " `,`" . $synsetid . "`,`" .$seqno . "`)";
     $result=mysql_query($sql);

    if(!$result)
    {
    die(mysql_error()); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Please stop writing new code with the ancient mysql_* functions. They are no longer maintained and community has begun the deprecation process . Instead you should learn about prepared statements and use either PDO or MySQLi.

Answer (score 2):

```
$sql="INSERT  INTO `wordnet50`.`table`  (`category`,`filename`,`wordid`,`synsetid`,`seqno`) VALUES (`" . $cat . "`,`" . $file. "`,`" . $wordid. " `,`" . $synsetid . "`,`" .$seqno . "`)";
```

You need to remove "`" from the above query in the values only and replace it with " ' " (single quote)

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks for field names and single quotes for the values.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `wordnet50`.`table` (`category`,`filename`,`wordid`,`synsetid`,`seqno`)
        VALUES ('$cat', '$file', '$wordid', '$synsetid', '$seqno')";
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be wrapped with single quotes not with back tick.

```
$sql = "INSERT  INTO `wordnet50`.`table`  (`category`,`filename`,`wordid`,`synsetid`,`seqno`) VALUES ('" . $cat . "','" . $file. "','" . $wordid. "','" . $synsetid . "','" .$seqno . "')";
```

`BackTick` escapes **[MYSQL Reserved WORDS](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html)**.

Answer (score -2):

if u can post ur db schema than it will be easy to check, as of now it look like u have a field as alt.atheism1111 which can be the show stopper

or use this:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO `wordnet50`.`table` (`category`,`filename`,`wordid`,`synsetid`,`seqno`)
    VALUES ('$cat', '$file', '$wordid', '$synsetid', '$seqno')";
```

Comment: yes ur right,i too figured this out,though its strange because i did try single quotes but it didnt work.the combination of putting the column names within ` and values within single quotes made it work! hope this helps other people with similar problems